Table 'any table' doesn't exist in engine without moving anything
Today after I guess a month or so I rebooted my server and now I get
Table 'ANY TABLE' doesn't exist in engine

in every InnoDB table that I want to open in phpMyAdmin. My ISAM tables are fine and working. I saw other people had the same problem after moving files from an old backup to a MySQL directory, but I did not do that.
Another odd thing is I have a backup from a machine (it's VMware), but when I recover from those (I tried a backup from 2 days ago and a 1 week old backup) I get the same error, but the database was working fine until today.
So I have no SQL backup and just a VMware machine backup, but even a 2 week old full machine backup is not solving my problem. I guess it's because of a change I made a long time ago, but it did not show up until the server reset. Is there is anything I can do to restore my database and get my data back?
I'm using XAMPP on Linux. There is no error in running MariaDB. InnoDB force recovery did not help even 6. I moved all data folder +  ib_logfiles + ibdata1 on a new XAMPP, but exactly same the error appears.

Your title says Table '*' but the question says Table ''. Which is it? You'll need to escape the * character to enter it literally in the text.

@Barmar i mean any table

What does the table definition look like?

@RickJames hello i attacked photo in answer section (My ISAM tables are fine and working)

i worked like 3 days on fixing it with like every solution on internet,
but only thing that worked for me to restore my data was  stellar repair for mysql software and its around 200$
because its reading .ibd files and and .frm files with ibdata1 and ib_logs files directly without connecting to mysql and give you sql output of your data
since i did not have sql backup and only had Full VmWare machine backup and those were corrupted too for unknown reason that was my only choice
image from old phpmyadmin:

